# Import Large Excell file to postgres with multiple optional dependencies with parents

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am using Postgres 9.3 and PHP in a application.

I would like to import Large Excell file to postgres with multiple optional dependencies with parent tables (basically I have to check if row exist with these parents).

I have done it using php for loop but it seems much slow. So I have to come with a solution in postgres function in database layer.

Can anybody tell me how can I send php array to postgres function and loop over the array in postgres function, implement the business rule in loop and
insert individual row into a table.

Answer (score 0):

The most quick interface for bulk load to PostgreSQL is COPY API. With this API you are sending to PostgreSQL blocks of lines (in strings) of values separated by selected separator. This method is very fast. You can load parent tables to hash tables (the check should be quick), and checked data can send to Postgres.

I am looking to PHP manual - there is function [pg_copy_from](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php), but working with large arrays in PHP can be difficult due memory usage (but it is terribly simple). Little bit more difficult, but without high memory requirements is way with function [pg_put_line](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-put-line.php).

```
<?php 
    $conn = pg_pconnect ("dbname=foo");
    pg_query($conn, "CREATE TABLE bar (a int4, b char(16), d float8)");
    pg_query($conn, "COPY bar FROM stdin");
    pg_put_line($conn, "3\thello world\t4.5\n");
    pg_put_line($conn, "4\tgoodbye world\t7.11\n");
    pg_put_line($conn, "\\.\n");
    pg_end_copy($conn);
?>
```

Comment: It will not serve my purpose.How could I write business logic for individual row and how could I check individual row exist in under it's parent.

Comment: It can do on client side - almost all ETL process work like it.